# Why precision of long double is not required to be higher than precision of double?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, language-lawyer, c11

C11:

```
DBL_DECIMAL_DIG   10
LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG  10

DBL_DIG           10
LDBL_DIG          10

#define DBL_MAX   1E+37
#define LDBL_MAX  1E+37
#define DBL_MIN   1E-37
#define LDBL_MIN  1E-37
```

C11:

> the set of values of the type double is a subset of the set of values of the type long double

Question: why C11 requires that precision of `double` > precision of `float`, but does not require that precision of `long double` > precision of `double`?

Comment: "C11 requires that precision of double > precision of float" --> not quite.  "C11 requires that _minimum_ precision of double > _minimum_ precision of float".  An implementation could use the same precision for `float, double, long double` if it was great enough.

Comment: Re “why C11 requires that precision of `double` > precision of `float`”: No, it does not. The minimum precision it requires of `double` exceeds the minimum precision it requires of `float`, but it does not require the precision of `double` to exceed the precision of `float`.

Comment: This seems consistent with existing requirements for integers.  `long` is not required to be strictly longer than `int`, nor is `short` required to be strictly shorter.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica [`long double` does exist in C89](https://web.archive.org/web/20161223125339/http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt), http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.html. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Language_Reference

Comment: Hmmm, So `long double` did exist in C89.

Comment: @NateEldredge The minimum size (in bits) for `int` and `long int` is [16 and 32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) accordingly. Then why  `double` and `long double` have the same minimum precision and minimum range?

Comment: @M.M Any ideas?

Comment: @pmor: I don't know that any explicit rationale was given.  The obvious guess would be that the standard authors wanted to give implementations the option of providing a type with strictly greater precision than `double` if it made sense for their platform, but not to require them to do so if it didn't make sense.  So a programmer can write code using `long double`, gain extra precision on platforms that choose to provide it, and still have their code compile and run with double precision on the rest.